# How to import photos library from a Mac SSD to Windows?

Tags: windows, photos, ssd, external-disk, data-transfer

Following the death of my Macbook Pro, I have an SSD with all my photos on it, stored as a Photos library.

- How can I extract all the photos that are in it and transfer them to
  Windows?
- My photos are sorted mainly by albums that I spent hours sorting by hand, not by Moments. Can I keep this information on Windows somehow,
  for instance by making new directories based on the albums, or using a specific pictures manager that can import this information?
- I have
  marked a lot of faces on my photos, can I get this information back?

I have not synchronized my pictures on iCloud, and I would like to avoid doing so because of privacy reasons, and because the library is quite big (>100GB).

Comment: I am thinking about encryption, format that macOS and windows could be compatible with and lastly whether iCloud for windows can read that information.

Comment: I have solved the problem of transferring the files to Windows, using a HFS drive reader.  I have access to my Photos library, which contains all the pictures and the metadata about albums, faces, etc. My problem now is : can I transfer the albums I made on Mac to Microsoft Photo ?